# Create two arrays to count the occurence of random numbers between 1 and 25 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am currently attempting to write a script where I want to use both a number and a counter array that use for loops to output a list of random numbers, and how often these numbers occur in the output when indexed in a for...in loop.

I have tried using lengths of the array and integers within the loop syntax
combined with if statements in the counter loop, and a random variable inside the numbers loop to generate the numerical output. I also wrote some code to pass these values into the counters array, but so far have been unsuccessful.

var count = 0;

```
        var counters = new Array(25);
        for (var i = 0; i < counters.length; i++) {
            /*if (count > 0) { 
            counters++;
            }*/
            if (count > 0)
                count++;
            //return count;                
        }

        var numbers = new Array(25);
        for (var i = 1; i <= 25; i++) {

            var random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 25);
            numbers[i] = random;
            counters[random] = parseInt(counters[random]) + 1;
        }                       


        for (index in numbers, counters) {

            document.write("<p>" + numbers[index] + " occurs " + counters[index] + " time(s)" + "</p>");
            //document.write("<p>" + numbers[index] + "</p>");
        }
```

As an example I am expecting to to output this:

1 occurs 1 time(s)

3 occurs 1 time(s)

5 occurs 2 time(s)

7 occurs 1 time(s)

8 occurs 1 time(s)

10 occurs 1 time(s)

12 occurs 3 time(s)

13 occurs 2 time(s)

14 occurs 5 time(s)

18 occurs 2 time(s)

19 occurs 1 time(s)

20 occurs 2 time(s)

22 occurs 1 time(s)

23 occurs 2 time(s)

But this is what I'm currently getting:

19 occurs NaN time(s)

15 occurs NaN time(s)

1 occurs NaN time(s)

16 occurs NaN time(s)

22 occurs NaN time(s)

2 occurs NaN time(s)

8 occurs NaN time(s)

16 occurs NaN time(s)

16 occurs NaN time(s)

15 occurs NaN time(s)

23 occurs NaN time(s)

24 occurs NaN time(s)

17 occurs NaN time(s)

22 occurs NaN time(s)

Comment: because `parseInt(undefined) + 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you never fill in the values of the array so you are using parseInt() with an undefined value.

```
 var counters = new Array(25).fill(0);
```

other option is see if it has a value, if not use zero

```
counters[random] = (counters[random] || 0) + 1
```

And for the output just loop over it

```
for (i=0; i<counters.length; i++) {
  document.write("<p>" + i + " occurs " + counters[i] + " time(s)</p>");
}
```

Comment: how would we do it with the for in loop?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Map` as a lookup:

```js
let lookup = new Map();

for (var i = 1; i <= 25; i++) {
  const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25);
  
  if(lookup.has(rand)) {
    const count = lookup.get(rand);
    console.log(`${rand} has occurred ${lookup.get(rand)} time(s)`);
    lookup.set(rand, count + 1);
  } else {
    lookup.set(rand, 1);
  }
}
```